# How can I get the "Copy Link" from a document on SharePoint Online document library using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a way to get the link that you get when you press copy link on a document from sharepoint online document library. 
I need to retrieve this link programmatically using powershell.
any advice and thoughts?

Here is a picture of the link highlighted in blue.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up constructing the link dynamically. 
So Here is what I ended up doing to get the link:

1. use the cmdlet Get-PnPListItem
2. retrieve each UniqueID for each item in the library
3. Here is an example

   $UniqueID = (Get-PnPListItem -id 231 -List Budget).FieldValues.UniqueID
4. the $UniqueID = e1a1f20f-4b7d-4y16-x021-3469bde98088

Here are the link steps:

1. https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Site/subsite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={
2. e1a1f20f-4b7d-4y16-x021-3469bde98088
3. }&action=edit

at the end just construct all steps to build your link dynamically. 
[https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Site/subsite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={e1a1f20f-4b7d-4y16-x021-3469bde98088}&action=edit](https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Site/subsite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7Be1a1f20f-4b7d-4y16-x021-3469bde98088%7D&action=edit)

In the end the only id you will be changing is the unique id between the curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Microsoft Graph API. There are examples and documentation around the web but it is in Beta so keep in mind the process might change.

You can use `Get` on the sharepoint site and see the drive objects, Then you can connect to them using the `Drive ID` and look at the `webURL` property of the files.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/drive

Comment: The Microsoft Graph API works better with OneDrive Files. applying it to SPO document library is trickier.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? Graph API isn't different between the SPO doc lib objects and OneDrive objects, because OneDrive uses SPO DL for its back end storage. The API interfaces are the same, It also allows impersonation, proper authentication and service account management.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Nick says, we can use the Graph API to achieve this requirement in particular the "[createLink](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink)" endpoint.

We can do a POST request with following body (or similar)

```
{
  "type": "edit",
  "scope": "organization"
}
```

and the request URL can be one of the following

> - /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem/createLink
> - /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/createLink
> - /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{drive-item-id}/createLink